# Sencha Touch Sencha Cmd build not updating

Tags: sencha-touch

Ive added an `alert()` in my primary mainview in the `initialize()` method

Ive tried every sencha command

- **sencha app build ios**
- **cordova build ios**
- **cordova build ios --release**

But when i run **xcode** and run it in the emulator it **never** gets hit.  Just to verify I modified my `index.html` title and added a label with value 1 in mainview.

If I run it under sencha web server it shows up properly.

But when I try to build it its not updating and when I look in `MyProject\cordova\www\index.html` is not being updated.

I have gotten it to work before so im not sure if im missing a step.

I have the latest sencha cmd and sencha touch
Any ideas?

**Update 1**

In the `index.html` I modified:

```
<title>Test1</title>
```

to

```
<title>Test2</title>
```

in my `app\view\MainView.js`:

```
    items:
    [
        {
            style: 'font-size: .8em',
            html: 'Version: 1.1'
        }
    ]
....
    initialize: function()
    {
        this.callParent(arguments);

        alert('this is another test');
    }
```

And when i run in **XCode**, none of the alerts show.  And the Version which was original 1 is still showing not 1.1

**Update 2**

My complete `index.html:`

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html manifest="" lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test2</title>

    <!-- The line below must be kept intact for Sencha Command to build your application -->
    <script id="microloader" type="text/javascript" src=".sencha/app/microloader/production.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
```

**Update 3**

When I run it in android emulator the changes took affect.  And then I ran the XCode and it took the changes.  Thats weird.  I run sencha app build native so that may be the missing step

Comment: Please share the code?

Comment: See above for the sample changes

Comment: I want to see your index.html plz.

Comment: Yes it works after I ran the command "sencha app build native"

Answer (score 1):

Try to run `alert()` **inside** the `index.html` and see the difference.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html manifest="" lang="en-US">
   <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test2</title>

    <!-- The line below must be kept intact for Sencha Command to build your application -->
    <script id="microloader" type="text/javascript" src=".sencha/app/microloader/production.js">
    <script>
        alert("This is a test alert message");
    </script>
   </head>
<body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip but the problem was missing this step:
=> sencha app build native
I've tried it 5 times now and the changes have taken everytime